# Is there a way to insert a contact into a Data Extension from a previous Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, subscriber-key

I would like to know how a contact can be introduced inside a new Data Extension after completing a Journey, without the need of having the subscriber key already inside that new Data Extension.

The challenge is that all of this needs to happen inside they Journey, without the need of using Queries, and without the new Data Extension having the subscriber key (i.e. we don't want to use the "Update contact" activity)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the logic against the Update Contact activity here? While it's name contains the word "Update" it is capable of inserting new records into another data extension

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak thanks for the clarification. How could I do it?